# ¿Como almacenar el token JWT en la aplicación web asp.net o como manejar para hacer el login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, jwt

como puedo hacer para almacenar el token que me devuelve una api al consumirla con asp.net mvc 5 o bien de que forma seria la correcta para manejar esto al momento de logear?.

Se uso JWT para generar el token.

Cabe señalar que desde la api se hace la autenticacion, solo resta validar el token que me trae el response al hacer el post y almacenarla de alguna forma para poder reutilizar ese token en las demás solicitudes post con el HttpClient para agregarlo a la cabecera authorization.

Metodo que retorna el token

```
static async Task<Object> PostLoginAsync(Login model, string path)
    {
        RootObject RootObject = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            RootObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
        }

        return RootObject;
    }
```

Metodo HttpClient

```
public static HttpClient GenerateClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");

        return client;
    }
```

El token que me genera debería decodificarlo para poder recuperar su contenido y validar la key secret para luego almacenarlo en algo global y utilizarlo en cada request post en el HttpCLient en su authorization  `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token")`

Answer (score 1):

En un WebAPI almacena el Token en memoria según el siguiente código:

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/WebAPIBase/blob/master/Utils/JwtManager.cs

```
private static MemoryCache cache;

public static string GenerateToken(string username, int expireMinutes = 20)
{
    cache = new MemoryCache("CachingProvider");

    var hmac = new HMACSHA256();
    var key = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.Key);

    var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                }),

        Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),

        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);

    cache.Add(token, key, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);

    return token;
}
```

Comment: Pero eso seria como dices en el webapi y no tengo acceso al source de la api. Mi pregunta va enfocada a como manejar el token desde mi aplicación web que es la que esta consumiendo el servicio api.